# Ways to be Abominable when you can't vote to close/delete

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I know what the hats are, though I haven't been actively trying to get them. However, I do check to see what I get the hats for. One of these hats is the Abominable, this hat is achieved by:

> Participating in successfully closing or deleting a question.

I know I don't have the privilege of casting close or delete questions so my account was not accessed without my knowledge. How did I get this hat if I don't have the privileges to get it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Under *some circumstances*, you can get this hat by *flagging* for closure (as a duplicate, off-topic, etc.). What the specific circumstances are is unknown; a Stack Overflow developer has stated that [flags never count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288390/2952320) for this hat, but a lot of users (including yours truly on Hardware Recommendations, English Language & Usage, Mathematics, Puzzling, Bitcoin, Electrical Engineering, Health, and two other sites which I can't remember) have indeed received Abominable hats for just flagging a question that was later closed.

Comment: +1 Yeah, I also got that hat on music.stackexchange.com for just flagging. Maybe it's first one to flag or something similar...

Comment: All hat questions I have seen are answered by you, did you get a secret hat for this?

Comment: @Oriol sadly, no. I can't even get a [winterbash-2016] tag badge, because the tag needs to be used in 100 questions in order to hand out tag badges. *stops whining*

Comment: Yeah, I got Abominable for flagging as a duplicate. The post was later hammered and I got the hat.

Comment: Which is pretty suprising to me IMO, because when a question gets closed, those who flagged but can't participate in closing won't get mentioned as one of the people responsible for the close/deletion of the question.